# I am unable to pad a predefined class in bootstrap using my CSS file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

**html**

```
  <section id="title">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
       <a class=" navbar-brand">tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
       <ul class ="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>

  </nav>





    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="first">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</section>
```

**css**

```
 body
{
 font-family: Montserrat;

}


    
#title
{
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: #fff;
}

.first
{
  font-family : Montserrat-black;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;

  }
  .container-fluid
  {
    padding: 3% 15%;

    }
```

**img**
[This the output of my webpage. I just want more padding from left and right for my <div = class="container-fluid> element in <section id="title"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDFVW.jpg)

> 

I am learning from Angela Yu's Webdev udemy course. Currently learning bootstrap. In the above code I have use bootstrap class container-fluid for my div element in the . What I actually want is to have more padding for div element so that on the web page the navbar and iphone image and the text get padded from right and left.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 pl-5">
    <h1 class="first">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 pl-5">
    <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am saying that i used them but it isnt working the way i want

Comment: Implement the above line ( mentioned in the code )